# 'Various' or 'various of'?

Tags: grammar

Now, I'm certain they're both grammatically correct, but I'm curious of their usage; 'various of' seems rather archaic (it's used in Politics and the English Language by Orwell, for example). So, I presume it's either an archaic use, or the British use.

Can anyone tell me which?

Context:

> I list below, with notes and examples, **various of** the tricks by means of which the work of prose-construction is habitually dodged.

From George Orwell's "Politics and the English Language". He uses the word 'various' only twice in this essay, both of which precede the preposition 'of'.

Comment: Could you give us an example of its use complete with context?

Comment: I agree *various **of the** X's* is relatively "dated/starchy", but I certainly wouldn't say it's "archaic". Though quite why [it's fallen out of favour](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=various+of+the&year_start=1948&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvarious%20of%20the%3B%2Cc0), escapes me, since syntactically similar forms such as ***several / many / enough** of the X's* are still fine with or without ***of the***.

Answer (score 1):

'Various of' is neither archaic nor particularly British. I would say that Orwell is using it as a synonym for 'some of'. He considers that there are a number of tricks used for the purpose he names, and he is going to list some of them.